# Arranging buttons in a circular fashion and animate using css

Tags: html, css

There are three buttons. I want to arrange them in a circle. Is there a way to do it by putting them in the same div and then give some in div property, instead of giving the coordinates for each button?
 And how to make animations/ for example on clicking any button tha button should rotate and come to the top.

Comment: have a look at this http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-roundrr/

Comment: give any image link for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE STYLE

```
.Hfaraz {
background-color: #03F;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
float: left;
}
.Hfaraz:hover{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */

-webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }
```

THIS IS HTML

```
<div class="Hfaraz"></div>
<div class="Hfaraz"></div>
<div class="Hfaraz"></div>
```